# print rows from read_csv object with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Trying to print records from a .csv file with 2 conditions based on 2 columns (Georgraphy and Comment). It works when I put one condition on Geography column but does not work when I put conditions on Geography and Comments columns. Is this a syntax mistake? Thanks!

Works fine:

```
import pandas as pd
dt = pd.read_csv("data.csv", low_memory=False)
print(dt)
print(list(dt))
geo_ont = dt[dt.Geography=="Ontario"]
print(geo_ont)
```

Does not Work:

```
import pandas as pd
dt = pd.read_csv("data.csv", low_memory=False)
print(dt)
print(list(dt))
geo_ont = dt[dt.Geography=="Ontario" & dt.Comment=="TRUE"]
print(geo_ont)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks @NikhilGowdaShivaswmay - I googled many times but could not formulate my question to get proper result, appreciate the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the comment column is Boolean. So, Either you convert comment column to string or just use it as '1' or True. Here is the code,

```
import pandas as pd
dt = pd.read_csv("test.csv", low_memory=False)
print(dt.Comment.dtype)
geo_ont = dt[(dt.Geography=="Ontario") & (dt.Comment)]
      #OR
#geo_ont = dt[(dt.Geography=="Ontario") & (dt.Comment==True)]
       #OR
#geo_ont = dt[(dt.Geography=="Ontario") & (dt.Comment==1)]
print(geo_ont)
```

Comment: geo_ont = dt[(dt.Geography=="Ontario") & (dt.Comment==True)] - this is what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: You can use any of those. You just copy paste my code, it will work, Line number 4,6 and 8 are same, but different approach.